# Change subdomain every refresh of page using .htacess. Is this possible?

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, vhosts

I'm searching for a way to change subdomain each refresh of page. Example:

sub1.domain.com after refresh of page url change to sub2.domain.com ?

Is this possible ?

Any help is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: possible if you write a script that modifies .htaccess each request. But the nicer way is to use a script to redirect in the first place.